# How to return a message if pattern doesnt match in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I have this pattern on my input but I want to make a condition that checks if a pattern has been followed and if not it should return an error msg

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="clientPassword">Password*</label><br>
                <small>Passwords must at least 8 characters and contain at least 1 number, 1 capital, letter and 1 special character</small>
                <input id="clientPassword" name="clientPassword" type="password" required pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z].*$)">
            </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there anything not working?

Comment: You should use JS to check this

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm confused. The `pattern` parameter literally does what you want? If you type in something which doesn't match and try to submit then a popup will appear?